# Hiding div based on [data-counter]

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a cart icon on my website when the cart is empty. I'm not an expert in jQuery but I know the basics.

````js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".button-icon[data-counter]").is() == "0"){    
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").hide();
    }else{    
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").show();
    }
});

```
````

```html
<div class="menu-cart-wrapper">
  <a id="menu-cart__toggle_button" href="#">
    <span class="button-text"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span></span></span>
    <span class="button-icon" data-counter="0">
      <i class="eicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span "screen-only">Cart</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

With this the button is hidden at all times and I can't figure out why.

I've also tried with the span class "woocommerce-prize etc." and add .html after with == "0 " but that didn't work either.

Plz help!

Comment: Just to add, it's a wordpress website

Comment: `is()` should be `data('counter')` instead.  `is()` doesn't do anything.  It expects an input that will be evaluated against the result stack.  That's not what you are after here.  https://api.jquery.com/is  https://api.jquery.com/data  *Always* read up on the api for methods you are not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the data-counter from 1 to 0 it will hide:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var sp=document.getElementsByClassName('button-icon')[0].getAttribute('data-counter'); 

    if(sp === '0'){      
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").hide();
    }else{    
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-cart-wrapper">
  <a id="menu-cart__toggle_button" href="#">
    <span class="button-text"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span></span></span>
    <span class="button-icon" data-counter="1">
      <i class="eicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span "screen-only">Cart</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(".button-icon[data-counter]").data('counter') == "0"){    
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").hide();
    }else{    
        $(".menu-cart-wrapper").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-cart-wrapper">
  <a id="menu-cart__toggle_button" href="#">
    <span class="button-text"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">0&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">kr</span></span></span>
    <span class="button-icon" data-counter="1">
      <i class="eicon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span "screen-only">Cart</span>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```